# how to prevent cross site access

Tags: xss

ok i just did a test and it turns out that this is not blocked by the browser - which i kind of assumed because its the same way you can load jquery and still have access to the data it loads:

i have a script located here:
https://securedomain.com/cookie_test.php - it prints out the cookies as json

if i run this file here:
http://myotherdomain.com/cookie_test.php

the javascript loads with this content:

but it does not load with an AJAX request because of the same origin policy

it also looks like in order to work in the script tag, it has to be a valid js statement like:
data={secure_data:true}

but if i do it as just plain JSON, then it causes a javascript error:
{secure_data:true}

so am I correct in assuming that the data output in this file is safe, as long as i output JUST json in the json format? that it can't be retrieved by any other site on the clients browser?

Answer (score 0):

Should be, but if you are worried, you could always add a comment around the json, load it into the browser as text fron ajax, revert the commenting in javascript and then do a JSON.parse.

Making all cookies available this way looks like a bad idea from the side of secure domain though, as it will kill sensible things like HttpOnly cookies.